# Dit-on « son un an », « ses un ans » ou une autre expression ?

Tags: pluriel, accord, nombres

Pour parler d'un anniversaire, on dit *nous fêterons **ses deux ans*** ou *il a reçu de nombreux cadeaux pour **ses vingt ans***. Mais quand il s'agit du premier anniversaire, peut-on dire *son un an* ou *ses un ans* ? L'une de ces formules est-elle correcte ?

La formule correcte est très probablement *son premier anniversaire* mais je continue à m'interroger sur ce qui différencie *ses un ans* et *ses deux ans*, autrement dit, pourquoi cette expression ne *sonne bien* qu'à partir d'un âge supérieur ou égal au nombre deux.

Comment: De mon côté je dis "ses un an", mais j'avoue que c'est un peu bizarre grammaticalement, même si ça sonne bien à mon oreille. "Son premier anniversaire" par contre, ça règle la question !

Comment: À mon avis, "ses un ans" ne peut pas se dire vu que un est singulier et "an" ne peut pas prendre un "s". À moins de considérer an comme ensemble de 365 jours. Mais ça ne sonne pas. Autant mieux se limiter à "son premier anniversaire".

Comment: À cet âge là on compte encore en mois: ses douze mois.

Comment: @lnanikian Sauf que ça se dit, c'est un fait. Savoir comment l'écrire, c'est autre chose…

Comment: Dans le Figaro en ligne on lit ce mois-ci à propos des attaques du Bataclan : "les un an du 13 novembre". A hurler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

« Ses un an » et « ses un ans » sont choquants grammaticalement à cause de la rupture entre le pluriel et le singulier. Le premier l'est quand même beaucoup moins, parce qu'il y a déjà une rupture entre « ses » et « un an » : on ne devrait pas avoir une telle juxtaposition entre l'adjectif possessif et l'article indéfini. En revanche, l'absence d'accord entre *un* et *ans* touche aux fondamentaux de la langue.

Je pense que la formule correcte est « sa première année ». On sous-entend toujours qu'on fête la fin des années en question : « sa première année révolue », « ses deux ans révolus », … On peut bien sûr aussi parler de « son premier anniversaire », puis de « son deuxième anniversaire », etc.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ses+un+an%2Cses+un+ans%2Cson+un+an%2Cses+deux+ans&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cses%20deux%20ans%3B%2Cc0) ne trouve pas un nombre significatif d'occurrences de « ses un an », « ses un ans » ou « son un an ». Si l'on fouille un peu plus, le premier exemple de « ses un an » (« Ton oncle a marché le jour de ses un an. ») est rapporté à « Madame A, le 2 septembre 1922 » dans [*Des Mots à la pensée : essai de grammaire française*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=DgMrAAAAIAAJ&q=%22ses+un+an%22&dq=%22ses+un+an%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=WIZKU6vJArCw7Abm34HYAw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg) de Jacques Damourette et Édouard Pichon en 1932. Il semble y avoir une analyse plus poussée dans [*L'Accord en français contemporain* de Paul Hoybe](http://books.google.fr/books?id=iz8TAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ses+un+an%22&dq=%22ses+un+an%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=WIZKU6vJArCw7Abm34HYAw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ) (1944), qui rapproche cette tournure de « vers les midi », « à midi précises » (désapprouvées par [Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/midi) qui n'accepte que « sur le midi et non sur les midi »). Il semble que dans des contextes qui appellent une quantité exprimée avec une unité (midi = douze heures, un an = douze mois), on puisse considérer la quantité comme un pluriel même lorsqu'elle est exprimée par une tournure grammaticalement singulière.

Si l'on s'en tient à la [sélection de Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22ses+un+an%22&hl=fr&biw=1000&bih=862&sa=X&ei=WIZKU6vJArCw7Abm34HYAw&ved=0CCcQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1980%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1989&tbm=bks) (attention au gros biais d'observation !), c'est dans les années 1980 que l'expression « ses un an » fait son apparition à l'écrit : « Son plus lointain souvenir doit remonter à ses un an » ([Moustapha Raith, *Palpitations intra-muros*, 1986](http://books.google.fr/books?id=PoD2QJ3fkMMC&pg=PA181&dq=%22ses+un+an%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=s4dKU_3nE4rx0gW4pYG4Aw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ)).

Pour ce qui est de « ses un ans », même si cela se trouve sur des blogs, les seules occurrences sur [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22ses+un+an%22&hl=fr&biw=1000&bih=862&sa=X&ei=WIZKU6vJArCw7Abm34HYAw&ved=0CCcQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1980%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1989&tbm=bks#hl=fr&q=%22ses+un+ans%22&tbm=bks) semblent être des accidents de numérisation (plus un [exercice de grammaire](http://books.google.fr/books?id=VE1ShW_0Kr0C&pg=PA229&dq=%22ses+un+ans%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=z4lKU6ayIoaG0AWFloCgBw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw)). On peut donc sans risque affirmer que cette tournure est grammaticalement incorrecte.

Même manque de citation fiable pour [« son un an »](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22ses+un+an%22&hl=fr&biw=1000&bih=862&sa=X&ei=WIZKU6vJArCw7Abm34HYAw&ved=0CCcQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1980%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1989&tbm=bks#hl=fr&q=%22son+un+an%22&tbm=bks), moins choquant grammaticalement cependant. Il reste le problème de la juxtaposition des déterminants. Paradoxalement, « ses un an » est moins gênant de ce point de vue parce qu'il impose un hiatus entre *ses* et *un*, alors que dans « son un an », le *un* appelle à être absorbé par l'autre déterminant.

J'en conclus que, suivant [la classification des évolutions de la langue](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/prescriptivist-vs-descriptivist-prescriptif-ou-descriptif/155#155), « ses un an » doit bien avoir atteint au moins le registre relâché, tandis que « son un an » est tout au plus un barbarisme néologique. Quant à « ses un ans », il reste une faute.

Comment: Je pense que "ses un an" est la meilleur des solution et la plus "Française".

Comment: Je suis d'accord, et par chez moi elle s'utilise sans choquer. Belle explication d'ailleurs Gilles !

Answer (score 3):

Une petite citation de l'ouvrage ***Les expressions verbales figées de la francophonie: Belgique, France, Québec, Suisse*** de **Béatrice Lamiroy** et **Jean-René Klein**, 2010, ISSN 1272-2235 :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Le pluriel français commence à deux. « Les un an » est une hérésie. On ne peut pas dire non plus « les un an et demi », ni « les un million », ni « les un million et demi ». Il faut dire « le million » et « le million et demi ».

En revanche, « mon un an » sonne mal. Il faut donc le dire autrement, si tant est qu'on sache dire quoique ce soit à un an (et pas « un ans »).

Comment: Le dire autrement : « ses douze mois » ? J'ai constaté qu'on comptait généralement l'âge en mois jusqu'au deuxième anniversaire (constat purement empirique).

Answer (score -1):

Jamais je n'emploierais *ses un an*, qui n'est pas du tout français...
Je suis étonné que personne n'ait cité la solution la + logique et parfaitement française : **son année** !  Par contre ça peut faire penser à l'année entière plus qu'à son échéance... ce qui semble bizarrement ne pas être le cas dans *ses deux ans*...
Je l'emploie (peut-être un peu par provocation et humour) mais je préfère dire ou écrire « *sa première année* ».

Comment: Lisez la réponse de Gilles, "*sa [première] année*" était déjà mentionné.

Comment: « Fêter ses un an » est tout à fait français, « fêter son année » n'a pas le même sens.